# AVD android emulator refuse to start on Linux

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, emulation, android-virtual-device

I tried to setup eclipse for android dev using linux but my major problem now is the android emu refuse to start. It starts and then closes. I use windows 7 and it works fine but my windows at times takes time to boot or shutdown, so I thought of trying it out on linux.

Please Help!

Comment: assign less than 512MB of RAm while creating a new AVD and try to start your AVD

Comment: Its set to 512mb and I keep reducing it till I get to 200mb but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

are you setting the correct RAM value of the emulated device if it is greater than the physical RAM then your AVD might not start.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that maximum RAM size should be of `768M` of emulator in windows for 4gb of actual physical ram PC.

So make sure you have assign `768mb` for RAM.